# BreezeJS - delete entities with refrences in custom context provider

Tags: javascript, entity-framework, breeze

I have a [custom context provider](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/custom-efcontextprovider) to validate on server side.
Now i want to hard delete a customer entity with all his child entities (addresses, emails, etc.)

1. Customer

   - Addresses
   - Emails
   - ...

Is a custom context provider the best way to check and remove the entity and the referenced child entities?

The code:

```
class CustomContextProvider : EFContextProvider<CustomContext>
{
    protected override bool BeforeSaveEntity(EntityInfo entityInfo)
    {
        switch (entityInfo.EntityState)
        {
            case EntityState.Deleted:
                if (entityInfo.Entity.GetType() == typeof(Customer))
                {
                    var customer = (Customer)entityInfo.Entity;
                    var customerDb = Context.Customers
                                     .FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == customer.Id);

                    // my delete logic
                }
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

and on the client side

```
function deleteCustomer() {
       customer().entityAspect.setDeleted();
       return datacontext.saveChanges();
}
```

will be executed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work, except that you will still have the children marked as *undeleted* on the client.  One approach would be to 'detach' all of the children entities on the client in the promise callback from the SaveChanges call.  Detaching them works nicely in this case, because all you really want to do is forget about them on the client, since you will have already deleted them on the server. Does this make sense?